# Mapping item in a list to a list of lists

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I'm thinking of an efficient way to map names in a list to grouped index items in a list of lists.

Let's say I have this grouping:

```
g = [[0,1],[2]]
```

I also have this list:

```
names = ["canine", "dog", "feline"]
```

I want to return the mapped names to the grouping according to index:

```
result = [["canine","dog"], ["feline"]]
```

I'm not exactly sure how to do this or even how to do it efficiently. Here's what I have so far and it's not working.

```
final = []
for j in range(len(names)):
    for item in g:
        for inner in item:
            res = []
            if inner == j:
                res.append(names[inner])
        final.append(res)
print(final)
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: If you are slicing successive elements, it would make more sense to have `g = [2, 1]` to indicate the length of sublists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you probably want to loop over `g` not `names`. There's no reason to loop over `names` since you will index into it with the values `g`. In that case it seems like a simple list comprehension might be a better fit for this:

```
[[names[i] for i in sublist] for sublist in g]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `map` with `lambda` to achieve your final output:

```
g = [[0, 1], [2]]

names = ["canine", "dog", "feline"]

result = [map(lambda i: names[i], sub_list) for sub_list in g]
# Output: [['canine', 'dog'], ['feline']]
```